# Artifactory downloads terminate prematurely due to nginx reverse proxy configuration

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, artifactory

We found that downloads of files larger than 1G from Artifactory with an nginx reverse proxy in front of it were sometimes being terminated prematurely *sometimes*.

When downloading with curl, it was possible to resume the download using the `-C -` flag to automatically determine the correct range to resume the download from.

It turns out that the default nginx configuration parameter `proxy_max_temp_file_size` of 1024m causes a race condition when downloading larger files, where sometimes the entire payload is downloaded, and other times it stops at 1024m.

I'm wondering if anyone else has seen this and knows more about problem. We were able to "fix" it by increasing the `proxy_max_temp_file_size`, but I still have a nagging drive to understand why it sometimes works.

Answer (score 0):

Has happened to me with NGINX and Docker. Please try adding the following to turn of the buffering that may be causing it:

```
proxy_buffering off;
proxy_ignore_headers "X-Accel-Buffering";
```

Usually the answer for this type of issues. It may also explain the parameter mentioned, as the buffer may be using that max size (so, sometimes when nothing else is buffered it may work)